# how to copy file from local to remote via ssh

Tags: ssh, scp

this is how to shh to server

`ssh -p 2222 thatilike@192.185.21.105`

I want to copy file `logo.png` to `public_html` folder on server

This is what I tried

`scp ./logo.png -p 2222 thatilike@192.185.21.105:/public_html/`

Don't know why not work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

per `man scp`

> ```
>  -P port
>          Specifies the port to connect to on the remote host.  Note that this option is written
>          with a capital ‘P’, because -p is already reserved for preserving the times and modes of
>          the file in rcp(1).
>
>  -p      Preserves modification times, access times, and modes from the original file.
> ```

corrected syntax:

```
scp -P 2222 ./logo.png thatilike@192.185.21.105:/public_html/
```

example:

```
$ touch ./logo.png
$ scp -P XXXXX ./logo.png XXX@XXX.XXX:/tmp/
logo.png                                                             100%    0     0.0KB/s   00:00    
$
```

to check connectivity (via `ssh`) and target directory exist do following.

```
$ ssh -p XXXXX XXX@XXX.XXX 'if [ -d /tmp/ ] ; then ls -ld /tmp/ ; fi'
drwxrwxrwt  21 root  wheel  31232 Mar  3 23:04 /tmp/
$
```

Comment: I just your command. After enter, I wait for a while and I got this message `ssh: connect to host 192.185.21.105 port 22: Operation timed out
lost connection`

Comment: @angrykiwi I just revised it, try it again (assuming your host is up and source file and destination directory exists, it should work)

Comment: With updated commnad I got this message `scp: /public_html/: Is a directory`

Comment: @angrykiwi if use my line exactly, it'll work.

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't, I made video, https://youtu.be/jwRrwkXs8Xw

Comment: @angrykiwi see update in my answer, try that line as well

Answer (score 3):

Your command line doesn't specify the port number correctly.

As seen in the `scp` man page:

```
     -P port
             Specifies the port to connect to on the remote host.  Note that
             this option is written with a capital ‘P’, because -p is already
             reserved for preserving the times and modes of the file.
```